# Are values equal with multiple multidimenional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays

array_1 is multidimensional but the location of the value I need is

```
array_1['id']
```

array_2 is also multidimensional and the location is further down inside.

```
array_2['data']['id']
```

Now I am trying to execute my code only if (===) those 2 ID'S are identical.

Further Information is that this is a combination of 2 API'S but the code for the API'S is working fine because if I try to get information from both API'S it shows me.

Code:

```
$orders = $apiSeo->orders->get();
$parcels = $apiSend->parcels->get();

foreach($orders as $id => $order){
    if(($orders[$id]['paymentStatus'] == 'paid') || ($orders[$id]['paymentIsPost'] == true)){
        echo '<pre>';
        var_export($orders[$id]['id']);
        var_export($orders[$id]['lastname']);
        var_export($orders[$id]['paymentStatus']);
        var_export($orders[$id]['paymentIsPost']);
        echo '</pre>';
    }   
}
```

what have I tried adding:

```
foreach($parcels as $id2 => $parcel){
    if($orders[$id]['id'] === $parcels[$id2]['data']['order_id']){//}
}
```

and also no succes with array_key_exists or in_array.

My output with var_export or var_dump is nothing when adding these pieces of code. also no error while i have error reporting on. So I Am clueless where the mistake or miscode lies.

**print_r request $parcels array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1440143
            [address] => xx
           [address_divided] => Array
            (
                [street] => xx
                [house_number] => 8
            )

        [city] => xx
        [company_name] => 
        [country] => Array
            (
                [iso_2] => NL
                [iso_3] => NLD
                [name] => Netherlands
            )

        [data] => Array
            (
                **[seoshop_order_id] => 15802836** HERE!
            )

        [date_created] => 03-03-2016 07:41:39
        [email] => xx@live.nl
        [name] => xx
        [postal_code] => xx
        [reference] => 0
        [shipment] => Array
            (
                [id] => 10
                [name] => DHL Complete with signature
            )

        [status] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1000
                [message] => Ready to send
                [history] => 
            )

        [telephone] => xx
        [tracking_number] => JVGL0
        [label] => Array
            (
                [normal_printer] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => https://panel.sendcloud.nl/api/v2/labels/normal_printer/1440143?start_from=0
                        [1] => https://panel.sendcloud.nl/api/v2/labels/normal_printer/1440143?start_from=1
                        [2] => https://panel.sendcloud.nl/api/v2/labels/normal_printer/1440143?start_from=2
                        [3] => https://panel.sendcloud.nl/api/v2/labels/normal_printer/1440143?start_from=3
                    )

                [label_printer] => h1
            )

        [order_number] => ORD03
        [carrier] => Array
            (
                [code] => dhl
            )

        [tracking_url] => xx
    )
```

**print_r request $orders array** To big to copy and place all array, not necessary also since no other info is needed.

```
 Array
(
     [0] => Array
        (
            **[id] => 15817386** HERE!
```

Comment: can you post `print_r` of both array in question

Comment: @ChetanAmeta added mister! Hope you have any insight for me.

Comment: you want to compare `seoshop_order_id` from parcel array?

Comment: @ChetanAmeta yes, that id is equal to the 'id' from order array

Comment: « what have I tried adding: ». Where did you add this? In the first foreach? Also it is very weird to write `$parcels[$id2]`, you could have a more readable code by using `$parcel` which is the same thing (same applies to `$orders[$id]` => `$order`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work, Thanks for anyone that tried to understand me and/or help.!

```
 for($x = 0 ; $x < 50 ; $x++){
                    if(($orders[$x]['paymentStatus'] == 'paid') ||           ($orders[$x]['paymentIsPost'] == true)){
                        if($orders[$x]['id'] == $parcels[$x]['data']['seoshop_order_id']){

                                echo '<pre>';
                                var_export($orders[$x]['id']);
                                var_export($orders[$x]['lastname']);
                                var_export($orders[$x]['paymentStatus']);
                                var_export($orders[$x]['paymentIsPost']);
                                var_export($parcels[$x]['name']);
                                var_export($parcels[$x]['data']['seoshop_order_id']);
                                echo '</pre>';
                        }   
                    }
                }
```